# Parsing Twitter using DomDocument in C#

Tags: c#, .net, domdocument

Can anyone tell me why this won't find any nodes?

```
 WebClient Client = new WebClient();      
   Stream stream =  
     Client.OpenRead("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=JetBlueCheeps");

   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

   mgr.AddNamespace("google", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
   mgr.AddNamespace("openSearch", "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/");
   mgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
   mgr.AddNamespace("twitter", "http://api.twitter.com/");
   mgr.AddNamespace("georss", "http://www.georss.org/georss");

   doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
   XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("entry", mgr);
```

I am trying to read all the "entry" nodes, and they are present in the document, because this alternate method is working :

```
 XmlNode fentry = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[9];
  while (fentry.NextSibling != null)
            fentry = fentry.NextSibling;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its expecting an XPath to the nodes that you want selected. Try:

`XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("feed/entry", mgr);`

or

`XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//entry", mgr);`

if you want to match all `feed` nodes irrespective of where in the document hierarchy they are.

Comment: Tried those XPath's as well as many others. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Overriding the default namespace works. System.Xml did not like mgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"). So I put my own name where the empty string is there, and of course experimented with variations of the XPath as suggested by Bhargav above. Thanks all! @BhargavBhat